# Making Polymer.dart elements appear, and using style with Polymer.dart

Tags: css, dart, polymer

I am on my first Dart project. I already managed to make working tabs.
But I am having trouble making my polymer element appear in the web browser.
The output should be a light grey ribbon, like in Office 2007+.
The only thing I can see is a 0x0px light grey vertical line.
If I use classic HTML and CSS (no templating) it works.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>CVWebkit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CVWebkit.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="scripts/packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/dart" src="scripts/cvwebkit.dart"></script>
        <script src="scripts/packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

          <polymer-element name="zone-ruban">
                <template>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CVWebkit.css"/>
                <div class="ruban">
                  <template repeat="{{zone in zones}}">
                    <div id="{{zone}}">
                      <template repeat="{{fonction in fonctions}}">
                        <img src="{{fonction}}"/>
                        <span class="titre_ruban">{{fonction}}</span>
                      </template>
                    </div>
                </template>
                </div>
                </template>
              </polymer-element>
    </body>
```

And here is my Dart code (cvwebkit.dart):

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'packages/polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'packages/observe/observe.dart';


void main() {
  querySelectorAll(".onglet")..onClick.listen(ouvrirOnglet);
}

@CustomTag('zone-ruban')
class ZoneRuban extends PolymerElement with Observable {
  final List zones = toObservable(['navigation', 'composants', 'propcompo', 'utilisateur']);
  final  List fonctions = toObservable(['Navigation', 'Composants', 'Propriétés du composant', 'Données utilisateur']);
  ZoneRuban.created: super.created();
}
```

The CSS :

```
.ruban {
    background-color: transparent;
    top:0px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    position: inherit;
}

#navigation{
    width:10%;
}

#composants{
    width:25%;
    left:10%;
}

#propcompo{
    width:40%;
    left:35%;
}

#utilisateur{
    width:25%;
    left:75%;
}

.titre_ruban {
    left:0%;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    position:inherit;
    text-align:center;
    color:gray;
    text-shadow : 0px -1px 1px #000 ;
    height:15%
}

.contenu_ruban {
    top:0px;
    height:85%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:central;
    position:inherit;
}

.user_menu {
    display:none;
}
```

Any idea why the ribbon isn't appearing?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like

```
:host {
  display: block;
}
```

in your elements CSS.